# Request method POST not allowed in CORS policy

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-core, cors

I use asp.net core 2.1 to build web API and use ajax on my web to request the api.

First I got problem on the GET method, I use a [chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) to solve the problem.

But I still can't work on the post method.

On the webpage

```
POST https://localhost:5001/api/chatbot 400 (Bad Request)
```

The Visual Studio show the Exception.

> [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)
>         Request starting HTTP/1.1 OPTIONS https://localhost:5001/api/chatbot
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 OPTIONS https://localhost:5001/api/chatbot
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService:Information: Policy execution failed.
>   [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[5]
>         Policy execution failed.
>   [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[7]
>         Request method POST not allowed in CORS policy.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService:Information: Request method POST not allowed in CORS policy.
>   [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
>         Request finished in 21.587ms 204

And I already use cors in **Startup.cs** - **ConfigureServices()**

```
options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", policy =>
            {
                policy.AllowAnyOrigin()
                      .AllowAnyHeader()
                      .AllowAnyMethod()
                      .AllowCredentials();
            });
```

**Startup.cs** - **Configure()**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        string swwwRootPath = env.WebRootPath; 
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        //app.UseCors(builder => 
        //builder.WithOrigins("file:///").AllowAnyHeader());

        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        app.UseCors(builder => {
            builder.WithOrigins("file:///").AllowAnyHeader();
        });

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

And my ajax function

```
var json = {"channel":"web", "message":"", "messagetype":"text", "userid":"xxx", "nodeid":nodeid};
$.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "https://localhost:5001/api/chatbot",
        data: json,
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success:...
```

My Controller

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ChatbotController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    public ActionResult<string> Post([FromBody]RequestModel request)
    {...
```

**RequestModel**

```
public class RequestModel
{
    public string channel { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string messagetype { get; set; }
    public string userid { get; set; }
    public string nodeid { get; set; }
}
```

Both **GET** and **POST** Method I can get the correct response when I using **Postman**.

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: By the way, the `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers must be sent by the server in _response_ to an OPTIONS request, not be the client in a _request_ as it seems you are trying here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** now that you provided more code it is clear.
This

```
    app.UseCors(builder => {
        builder.WithOrigins("file:///").AllowAnyHeader();
    });
```

overrides the initial global cors-settings and this is why it is not working. Enabling cors for a function or a controller doesn't sound like a good idea. CORS is for safety within browsers. You file:/// doesn't make sense here and is not necessary.

Adjust the method call `app.UseCors();` to `app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");`. You have to provide the name you have defined.

Comment: Still the same error? Can you provide the controller code as well please? Also can you try removing the headers from your Ajax request? They are set by the server in the response, not by the client in the request.

Comment: Alsami I use [EnableCors("CorsPolicy")], and it works now, but it still have SerializableError

Comment: Can you provide your whole startup code please? Is it possible, that you do app.UseMvc() before app.UseCors(...) ? Writing enablecors above each controller doesn't sound like the proper solution.

Comment: I put Startup Configure() on

Comment: thanks, could I ask why only Post method have this problem?

Comment: Yes. There are safe-requests (GET), and everything CUD related is not a safe-request (POST, PUT, DELETE) which is a browser security restriction. Read more about CORS here: https://www.codecademy.com/articles/what-is-cors

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I had to add this line of code above my controller as well, to allow that actual call. Please note that you can alter the headers and method attributes as this will allow everything...

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://yoursitenamehere.org", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class SampleController : ApiController
{}
```

Or you can replace the "http://yoursitenamehere.org" with * inorder to again allow everything. Dont forget to change this before releasing to prod, lol.